# postgreSQL uuid generation

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
select uuid_generate_v4() as one, uuid_generate_v4() as two;
```

"one" uuid and "two" uuid are equal!

```
CREATE TABLE "TB"
(
  "Id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
  "Title" character varying NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT "TB_Class_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")
);
```

postgresql 9.0 pgAdmin 1.12.3

```
insert into "TB" ("Id", "Title") values (uuid_generate_v4(), '111');
insert into "TB" ("Id", "Title") values (uuid_generate_v4(), '111');
insert into "TB" ("Id", "Title") values (uuid_generate_v4(), '111');
```

or

```
insert into "TB" ("Title") values ('111');
insert into "TB" ("Title") values ('111');
insert into "TB" ("Title") values ('111');
```

result:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "TB_Class_ID"
DETAIL:  Key ("Id")=(12ab6634-995a-4688-9a9a-ee8c3fe24395) already exists.
```

whereas

postgreSQL maestro 9.2.0.4

```
insert into "TB" ("Id", "Title") values (uuid_generate_v4(), '111');
insert into "TB" ("Id", "Title") values (uuid_generate_v4(), '111');
insert into "TB" ("Id", "Title") values (uuid_generate_v4(), '111');
```

result: 1 rows affected;

I understand that maestro added records one by one, but why uuid_generate_v4() returns the same value after two calls? (In pgAdmin case).

And how can I add several rows by one request?

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.  Try `SELECT random() AS one, random() AS two;`.  I get two different values, whether or not I'm in a transaction.  `uuid_generate_v4` is a `VOLATILE` function, so I think the fault lies either in the uuid-ossp module, or the underlying library.

Comment: Yes "SELECT random() AS one, random() AS two"  get different values and i don't understand why uuid_generate_v4 get equal values

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Within a given transaction, the function `uuid_generate_v4()` returns the same value.

When statements are grouped together and run as "one command", there is one transaction, so every call to `uuid_generate_v4()` will return the same value.

The two ways to "fix" this are:

1. Make separate database calls every time you use the function (this is easiest)
2. Use a non-auto commit connection where you control the transactions and separate each usage within a `BEGIN; COMMIT` pair (this is a hassle - don't do this unless you have to)

Comment: Just FYI for everyone who came here from Google or whatever, but I don't think this is a bug or issue anymore.  "select uuid_generate_v4() as one, uuid_generate_v4() as two" works properly in my PostgreSQL 9.3/9.4 installs.  Like @peter-eisentraut said, it was probably a bug that was fixed a while back.

Answer (score 17):

At some point in the past, the `uuid_generate_*` functions were erroneously marked as `IMMUTABLE`, which would result in the behavior you show.  This has been fixed in all the latest minor versions, but you have to re-run the installation script (`uuid-ossp.sql`) to get the updated function definitions.  (You can also look into the installation script to verify that you have an up-to-date version.  The functions should be marked `VOLATILE`.)

Comment: I replaced IMMUTABLE for VOLATILE in `uuid-ossp.sql`

`select uuid_generate_v1() as one, uuid_generate_v4() as two` 

gives two different results but

`insert into "TB" ("Id", "Title") values (uuid_generate_v4(), '111');
insert into "TB" ("Id", "Title") values (uuid_generate_v4(), '111');
`
continues to give "duplicate key" error

Comment: The table definition you show above doesn't even have a unique constraint, so you are not telling us the full truth.

Comment: I'm sorry, post updated `CONSTRAINT "TB_Class_ID" PRIMARY KEY ("Id")`

Answer (score 5):

To avoid duplicates you can use generation like this:

```
select md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid AS new_id, id from table;
```

But, be careful: this generates UUID but it is not UUIDv4. See more: [Generating a UUID in Postgres for Insert statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement/)