# Generating a UUID in Postgres for Insert statement?

Tags: postgresql, uuid, postgresql-8.4

My question is rather simple. I'm aware of the concept of a UUID and I want to generate one to refer to each 'item' from a 'store' in my DB with. Seems reasonable right?

The problem is the following line returns an error:

```
honeydb=# insert into items values(
uuid_generate_v4(), 54.321, 31, 'desc 1', 31.94);
ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
LINE 2: uuid_generate_v4(), 54.321, 31, 'desc 1', 31.94);
        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I've read the page at: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html

I'm running Postgres 8.4 on Ubuntu 10.04 x64.

Comment: Postgres natively supports [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) as a data type, even capable of being indexed and used as primary key. But to *generate* a UUID value, such as to establish a default value for a column, you need a Postgres extension (a plugin). Many builds (distributions) of Postgres include such an extension but do not activate the extension. See the [correct answer by Craig Ringer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12505220/642706) to learn how to activate it.

Comment: If you have uuid-ossp installed & you still get this error try prefixing the function with your schema name, e.g. `select dbo.uuid_generate_v4()`

Comment: Just in case you want Postgres to generate the UUID for a column OUTSIDE the PK (Primary Key), I finally found a specific way to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75900798/501113

Comment: if you use Postgres 13+, no extension needed, just call `gen_random_uuid()`.  
Courtesy of https://stackoverflow.com/a/61970869/316343

Answer (score 680, accepted):

`uuid-ossp` is a contrib module, so it isn't loaded into the server by default. You must load it into your database to use it.

For modern PostgreSQL versions (9.1  and newer) that's easy:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

but for 9.0 and below you must instead run the SQL script to load the extension. See [the documentation for contrib modules in 8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/contrib.html).

For Pg 9.1 and newer instead read [the current contrib docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html) and [`CREATE EXTENSION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html). These features do not exist in 9.0 or older versions, like your 8.4.

If you're using a packaged version of PostgreSQL you might need to install a separate package containing the contrib modules and extensions. Search your package manager database for 'postgres' and 'contrib'.

Comment: I'm supposed to type: pg_config --sharedir to find out my shared directory in order to import the module but the command isn't working in either shell or inside the psql command prompt.

Comment: So I had to run sudo apt-get install libpq-dev in order to run pg_config --sharedir but now I don't have a 'contrib' folder inside my sharedir which is supposed to exist according to http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/contrib.html

Comment: @advocate You're using a distro-packaged PostgreSQL so you should be able to just `apt-get install postgresql-contrib` or similar. Try `apt-cache search postgresql |grep contrib` to find the package name you want.

Comment: sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib has successfully run. Then I had to run psql -d dbname -f SHAREDIR/contrib/module.sql and now it works!!! select uuid_generate_v1(); returns 1 now now. Thanks so much!

Comment: CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp"; is not working in postgresql-9.1 too , Error: could not open extension control file "/usr/pgsql-9.1/share/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory
 is coming while creating extension. can u help me what I am lacking ,my version of postgresql is 9.1.

Comment: @SatishSharma Please post a new question. Link back to this one if you think it's relevant. Include details like how you installed Pg, your OS, etc.

Comment: Note that if you don't install the `postgresql-contrib` package, you'll get the error: _ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/uuid-ossp.control": No such file or directory_

Comment: @DrewNoakes Yep, hence the last paragraph.

Comment: I posted that comment as the error string struck out on Google. Also it gives a  specific package name, for Ubuntu at least.

Comment: If you imported a db that has the uuid-ossp in the Extensions already,  uuid_generate_v4() might not work. If that's the case, just remove the extension, and create it again and it should work.

Comment: Using `IF NOT EXISTS` is good practice, especially in any sql scripts - it prevents an error from being issued if, say, you re-run the script, or transfer it to another system where it is already loaded.  (I just added it to the answer.)

Answer (score 517):

## Without extensions (cheat)

**If you need a valid v4 UUID**

```
SELECT uuid_in(overlay(overlay(md5(random()::text || ':' || random()::text) placing '4' from 13) placing to_hex(floor(random()*(11-8+1) + 8)::int)::text from 17)::cstring);
```

[image]

- Thanks to **@Denis Stafichuk** **@Karsten** and **@autronix**

---

Or you can simply get UUID-like value by doing this (if you don't care about the validity):

```
SELECT uuid_in(md5(random()::text || random()::text)::cstring);

output>> c2d29867-3d0b-d497-9191-18a9d8ee7830
```

*(works at least in 8.4)*

Comment: Is this better than `uuid-ossp`? `uuid_in` seems to return the same outputs for identical inputs. So, if you use it to create two UUIDs at the same exact time (or with the same results from `random()`), they'll be equal.

Comment: To follow up your PS:

SELECT `uuid_in(md5(random()::text || now()::text)::cstring);`

Comment: @MattDiPasquale Probably not in any sense "better" than using `uuid-ossp`, but I'm for instance working on a PostgreSQL instance where I don't have the sufficient privileges to install an extension.

Comment: The clear issue with just time is "What if the time hasn't changed yet?" Put that statement two into a select and you'll get the same result twice.

Comment: @JosephLennox: [`clock_timestamp()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) is the better alternative in either case  for this. Unlike `now()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` it is volatile and returns the actual current time. `SELECT uuid_in(md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::cstring);` Also, in modern Postgres, you can simply cast: `SELECT md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid` - no need for more magic. Use-case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8335376/939860

Comment: Nope. If this does work at all its sheer luck. a UUID has a format, its not just random hex chars thrown together.The first number of 3rd group is the uuid version for intance (usually 4 these days). If your application checks that digit to see what version of uuid its dealing with, and do something accordingly, it will fail in your code.

Comment: @Tuncay Göncüoğlu: It's fairly straightforward to generate a valid v4 UUID (the string overlay approach wastes 2 bits of randomness though): `select overlay(overlay(md5(random()::text || ':' || clock_timestamp()::text) placing '4' from 13) placing '8' from 17)::uuid;`

Comment: @Karsten, I've improved your sample by getting back those 2 bits of randmoness: `overlay(overlay(md5(random()::text || ':' || clock_timestamp()::text) placing '4' from 13) placing floor(random()*(11-8+1) + 8)::text from 17)::uuid;` this should compensate for both version and variant while still retaining the 2 LSB `10xx` from the variant part.

Comment: @autronix, actually you've broken it. You need to convert `floor(random()*(11-8+1) + 8)` to hex to make it right. Here's the corrected version: `select overlay(overlay(md5(random()::text || ':' || clock_timestamp()::text) placing '4' from 13) placing to_hex(floor(random()*(11-8+1) + 8)::int)::text from 17)::uuid;`

Comment: @ZuzEL: you should remove your top answer because we have a high probability for collisions if use now() which is effectively error-prone when being in a transaction while generating multiple uuids. Use clock_timestamp instead to avoid this.

Comment: @JohnRumpel I edited. Thanks for your attention to that collision problem.

Comment: When trying to parse the UUID generated from this in Java, and then calling `uuid.timestamp()` it complains that the uuid is not a time-based uuid, so something is fishy by using this.

Comment: @RobinJonsson nothing fishy. Version 4 of UUID is not time based. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)

Comment: I see no sense in using `clock_timestamp` in any of the approaches mentioned in the answer because the data is fed into `md5` anyway and therefore is lost. Thus we can simply use `md5(random()::text || random()::text)::uuid`: using `random` (returns `double precision`, i.e. 64bits) twice gives us 128bit of random information which is converted to a hexadecimal representation of a different (but still random) 128bit number by `md5`.

Comment: There are strict requirements about how a UUID is **generated** that are undetectable until you accidentally get a duplicate.  Just because it looks like a UUID and smells like a UUID does not mean it's a valid UUID.  [UUID4 is not supposed to be clock based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random))

Answer (score 316):

PostgreSQL 13 supports *natively* [gen_random_uuid ()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-uuid.html):

> PostgreSQL includes one function to generate a UUID:
>
> ```
> gen_random_uuid () → uuid
> ```
>
> This function returns a version 4 (random) UUID. This is the most commonly used type of UUID and is appropriate for most applications.

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=0b6d75598881ad5988fa4b7a12a8f6e0)**

Comment: I don't undertstand why there are so much other (non working) answer, it's as simple as this! should be the accepted answer

Comment: @pdem because PostgreSQL 13 is rather new. For instance, I am still working on server version 10. This seems the best alternative for version 13, though.

Comment: @borellini I understand, I actually have a production server in 12, I had to create this patch function to make it work `create function gen_random_uuid() RETURNS uuid as $$ SELECT md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid $$ LANGUAGE SQL;`

Comment: I like this polyfill, easy to upgrade with.

Comment: Which version of UUID does it generate?

Comment: @TheRealChx101 "This function returns a version 4 (random) UUID."

Comment: this is definitely the correct answer!

Answer (score 115):

The [answer by Craig Ringer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12505220/642706) is correct. Here's a little more info for Postgres 9.1 and later…

## Is Extension Available?

You can only install an extension if it has already been built for your Postgres installation (your *cluster* in Postgres lingo). For example, I found the [uuid-ossp](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html) extension included as part of the installer for Mac OS X kindly [provided](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload) by EnterpriseDB.com. Any of a [few dozen extensions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib.html) may be available.

To see if the *uuid-ossp* extension is available in your Postgres cluster, run this SQL to query the [`pg_available_extensions`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/view-pg-available-extensions.html) system catalog:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;
```

## Install Extension

To install that [UUID](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html)-related extension, use the [CREATE EXTENSION](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) command as seen in this this SQL:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

**Beware:** I found the QUOTATION MARK characters around extension name to be required, despite documentation to the contrary.

The SQL standards committee or Postgres team chose an odd name for that command. To my mind, they should have chosen something like "INSTALL EXTENSION" or "USE EXTENSION".

## Verify Installation

You can verify the extension was successfully installed in the desired database by running this SQL to query the [`pg_extension`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-extension.html) system catalog:

```sql
SELECT * FROM pg_extension;
```

## UUID as default value

For more info, see the Question: [Default value for UUID column in Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122623/default-value-for-uuid-column-in-postgres)

## The Old Way

The information above uses the new *Extensions* feature [added](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.1#Extensions) to Postgres 9.1. In previous versions, we had to find and run a script in a *.sql* file. The Extensions feature was added to make installation easier, trading a bit more work for the [creator of an extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-extensions.html) for less work on the part of the user/consumer of the extension. See my [blog post](http://crafted-software.blogspot.com/2011/10/extensions-in-postgres.html) for more discussion.

## Types of UUIDs

By the way, the code in the Question calls the function `uuid_generate_v4()`. This generates a type known as [Version 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_(random)) where nearly all of the 128 bits are randomly generated. While this is fine for limited use on smaller set of rows, if you want to virtually eliminate any possibility of collision, use another "version" of UUID.

For example, the original [Version 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)) combines the [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) of the host computer with the current date-time and an arbitrary number, the chance of collisions is practically nil.

For more discussion, see [my Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/122624/19079) on related Question.

Comment: And you can also use `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS ...` if you are not sure and don't want to check (in a script e.g.)

Comment: Version 4 UUIDs are fine for nearly any size data set, not only "limited use on smaller sets of rows." You would have to generate 1 billion UUIDs per second for about 85 years (or about 45 million terabytes of data, thousands of times larger than the biggest databases today) to even have a 50% chance of collision. Unless you're the NSA, Version 4 is fine for about any purpose. Version 1, on the other hand, suffered from the fact that MAC addresses are sequentially-assigned (and are often spoofed or unavailable), which is part of why later versions were introduced.

Comment: @Jazz I do not see how sequentially-assigned MACs or spoofed MACs are relevant to generating UUIDs, Unless a MAC you were using were being spoofed on another machine in same context where you were using the UUIDs, the spoofed MAC is irrelevant.

Comment: @Jazz As for random-based UUIDs, there is enough misinformation and misunderstanding about UUIDs being unreliable that I wanted to allay any concerns. While I agree that for most practical purposes a version 4 UUID from a properly constructed generator is sufficient, there is still *some* chance of collisions. Using the other versions such as version 1 virtually eliminates any chance of collision. That's why it was invented first.

Comment: @Jazz As for other versions being created after version 1, I have only heard that the motivation was for concerns over the privacy and security implications of disclosing the MAC (which could be useful to a network hacker), the location implied by the MAC, and the date-time.

Comment: @BasilBourque The issue with v1 isn't the probability of collision when correctly implemented, it's the probability of incorrect implementation. As Wikipedia puts it: "The uniqueness of version 1 and 2 UUIDs ... also depends on network card manufacturers properly assigning unique MAC addresses to their cards, which like other manufacturing processes is subject to error." Also, in some containerized or virtualized environments, true MAC addresses from the underlying hardware are not available. If many containers have the same MAC but their own clockseq counters, their v1 UUIDs may collide.

Comment: @BasilBourque Weaknesses in v1 are not the main point of my comment, though. Your original answer implies that v4 is not suitable for large datasets due to a higher probability of collision than v1. This is misleading and possibly false, though it is hard to calculate the collision probability for v1 because it is so implementation-dependent.

Comment: @BasilBourque For example, the node-uuid project calculates the probability of their clockseq counters being the same (so that two processes would generate the same sequence of v1 UUIDs) as 1 in 4.6e18. This is tiny, yes, but much more likely than the chance of immediate collision in v4, which is 1 in 5.3e36. Obviously the longer you generate v4 UUIDs the more likely a collision becomes, which is not true of v1, but you'd have to generate 1.52 billion v4 UUIDs before the probability of collision exceeded that of node's v1 implementation. Most people don't have 1.52 billion records per table.

Answer (score 90):

## `pgcrypto` Extension

As of Postgres 9.4, the `pgcrypto` module includes the [`gen_random_uuid()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html#AEN160804) function. This function generates one of the random-number based [Version 4 type of UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29).

Get contrib modules, if not already available.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib-9.4
```

Use `pgcrypto` module.

```
CREATE EXTENSION "pgcrypto";
```

The `gen_random_uuid()` function should now available;

Example usage.

```
INSERT INTO items VALUES( gen_random_uuid(), 54.321, 31, 'desc 1', 31.94 ) ;
```

Quote from [Postgres doc on `uuid-ossp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html) module.

> Note: If you only need randomly-generated (version 4) UUIDs, consider using the gen_random_uuid() function from the pgcrypto module instead.

Comment: Yes, but see also https://blog.starkandwayne.com/2015/05/23/uuid-primary-keys-in-postgresql/ where they warn about fragmentation and suggest uuid-ossp instead.

Comment: Actually, see https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20151222124018.bee10b60b3d9b58d7b3a1839%40potentialtech.com where the uuid fragmentation issue in Postgres is debunked

Comment: But postgres does have clustered indexes in the latest version, making the post linked in the above comment inconclusive and incorrect and we are right back to square 1.

Comment: @MichaelGoldshteyn: no, Postgres does **not** have clustered indexes (as of Postgres 12)

Comment: The article in the first comment has moved [here](https://www.starkandwayne.com/blog/uuid-primary-keys-in-postgresql/). TLDR, though, the second link about debunking the "fragmentation" issue found the article that started the myth, and it is based on databases with clustered indexes, which as @a_horse_with_no_name has said, postgres does not have. It has a function to do a one-time reordering of data so the keys are clustered, but it is not the same as SQL Server. SQL Server can store rows ordered by a key, and shuffles things around as new records are added to keep the keys in order.

Answer (score 72):

Update from 2021,
There is no need for a fancy trick to auto generate `uuid` on `insert` statement.

Just do one thing:

1. Set default value of `DEFAULT gen_random_uuid ()` to your `uuid` column.
   That is all.

Say, you have a table like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
    unique_id UUID DEFAULT gen_random_uuid (),
    first_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    phone VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (unique_id)
);
```

Now you need NOT to do anything to auto insert uuid values to `unique_id` column. Because you already defined a default value for it. You can simply focus on inserting onto other columns, and `postgresql` takes care of your `unique_id`. Here is a sample insert statement:

```sql
INSERT INTO table_name (first_name, last_name, email, phone) 
VALUES (
    'Beki',
    'Otaev',
    'beki@bekhruz.com',
    '123-456-123'
)
```

Notice there is no inserting into `unique_id` as it is already taken care of.

*About other extensions like `uuid-ossp`, you can bring them on if you are not satisfied with postgres's standard `gen_random_uuid ()` function. Most of the time, you should be fine without them on*

Comment: As Lukasz Szozda noted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61970869/13950739, `gen_random_uuid()` is available in _core_ PostgreSQL (so don't need to install any extension) as of PostgreSQL *13*.

Comment: At the bottom of this article: https://www.starkandwayne.com/blog/uuid-primary-keys-in-postgresql/ there is a discussion on a possible con of gen_random_uuid(). Any comment as to the validity of the statement?

Comment: if you mean `negative side effect with respect to keyspace fragmentation`, then: No, that is not an issue: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/20151222124018.bee10b60b3d9b58d7b3a1839%40potentialtech.com
– as mentioned in a comment on brillout's answer

Answer (score 8):

Postgres v13+

```
INSERT INTO your_table
VALUES (gen_random_uuid(), 'value column 2', 'value column 3')
```

Answer (score 5):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT uuid_in((md5((random())::text))::cstring);
```

After reading @ZuzEL's answer, i used the above code as the default value of the column id and it's working fine.

Answer (score 5):

The uuid-ossp module provides functions to generate universally unique identifiers (UUIDs)

uuid_generate_v1() This function generates a version 1 UUID.

1. Add Extension

> CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";

2. Verify Extension

> SELECT * FROM pg_extension;

3. Run Query

> INSERT INTO table_name(id, column1, column2 , column3, ...)  VALUES
> (uuid_generate_v1(), value1, value2, value3...);

Verify table data

Answer (score 2):

first, you need to add extension

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";`

Answer (score 2):

On postgres version less than 13:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto";

-- gives:

SELECT gen_random_uuid();
```

On postgres version 13+:

```sql
SELECT gen_random_uuid();
```

In context when you don't know the postgres version but presume it's at least 9, and it matters to you not to enable the extension unnecessarily:

```sql
DO
$do$
BEGIN
  IF current_setting('server_version_num')::integer < 130000 THEN
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgcrypto";
  END IF;
END
$do$

SELECT gen_random_uuid();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT uuid_generate_v5(uuid_ns_url (), 'test');
```