# Postgresql using uuid_generate_v1() generates error

Tags: postgresql, uniqueidentifier, newid

I'm trying to run this query in postgresql:

```
CREATE TABLE MMCompany
 (
    CompanyID uuid PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1(),
    Name VARCHAR (150) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(100),
    CompanyLogo BYTEA 
 );
```

i've read that `uuid_generate_v1()` replaces `newid()` of sql server but it doesn't work and i get the following error:

ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v1() does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

what is the right syntax?

Comment: I don't think this is a part of core postgresql, perhaps you need to install the corresponding extension first.

Comment: this post has the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement