# Adding uuid in table

Tags: postgresql, uuid

I want generate uuid in postgres to insert in a column

```
INSERT INTO "EnumMaster"(
            "EnumerationID", "Name", "Text", "Description")
    VALUES (?, 'asasas', 'asasds', 'asdasdsad');
```

EnumerationID has data type uuid
so how to generate new uuid and add in that coloumn

Comment: You need to install the extension `uuid-ossp` then you can use any of the function provided by the module: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html

Comment: after downloading how to install it please tell now its not downloading  page not found

Comment: Installation and use can be seen in this stackoverflow entry:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement