# Heroku, Rails, and ActiveUUID -- Heroku using old migration files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I'm getting
        PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
error when I try heroku rake db:migrate for my rails 4 app.

I was using SQLite for my rails app and wanted to use UUIDs, so I had ActiveUUID gem installed. when I realized I had to switch to Postgres for heroku, I went back and removed the ActiveUUID generation functions from the migration files, so I went from this:

```
     create_table :users, :id => false do |t|
     t.uuid :id, :primary_key => true, null: false, :limit => 32
     t.string :name, null: false
```

to this:

```
     create_table :users, :id => :uuid do |t|
     t.string :name, null: false
```

I also removed the ActiveUUID gem from the gem file and deleted reference to it in all my models. Followed by git add ., git commit, and git push heroku master. I even reinstalled the heroku tool belt, but I can't get rid of this error.

I also had a UUID helper file in the lib folder. I deleted this and pushed. However, when I cloned a copy of the heroku repo to see its contents, the helper file is still there.

Sorry if I've just missed something completely obvious. I learned what heroku is about two days ago and am still a total beginner with rails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement.

Comment: I have enable_extension 'uuid-ossp' in a migration file. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: It looks like it should work, but I would try `CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";` directly in your PG command line.  From your error, it doesn't look like this is enabled in PG.

Comment: Thank you! Want to post as an answer and I'll accept it, @steveklein?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Postgres command line, enter:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

This will enable the Postgres UUID extension so that it will be available for your use.