# Postgres UUID type error

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to create a UUID id in a table with PostgreSQL. I tried with:

```
id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4()
```

But I get:

> ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist 
>   HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I tried with adding the schema like: `id uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT public.uuid_generate_v4()` (as seen in a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement#12505220))

I also checked if the extension is there (`SELECT * FROM pg_available_extensions;`), and yes I have it installed in the PostgreSQL database:

[image]

I read that if the Postgres is runing in `--single` mode, this may not work, but I don't know how to test it or if there is any way to do it.

Somebody knows how I can resolve the problem? Or any other option?
Is it a good idea to use like this:

```
SET DEFAULT uuid_in(md5(random()::text || now()::text)::cstring);
```

Comment: "Note: If you only need randomly-generated (version 4) UUIDs, consider using the `gen_random_uuid()` function from the [`pgcrypto`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/pgcrypto.html) module instead."

Comment: i don't think you have `uuid-ossp` loaded

Comment: Did you maybe install `uuid-ossp` into a separate schema that is not on the search_path?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Because the function `uuid_generate_v4` is not found, it suggests that the extension `uuid-ossp` is not loaded

`pg_available_extensions` lists the extensions available, *but not necessarily loaded*.

to see the list of loaded extensions query the view [`pg_extension`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-extension.html) as such:

```
select * from pg_extension;
```

To load the `uuid-ossp` extension run the following:

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
```

***note**: this will require super user privileges.*

After the `uuid-ossp` extension is successfully loaded, you should see it in the `pg_extension` view & the function `uuid_generate_v4` should be available.

Comment: If I use: `select * from pg_extensions;` I get the error:  
  ERROR: relation "pg_extensions" does not exist. 
For the moment I'm using: `uuid_in(md5(random()::text || now()::text)::cstring)`

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a typo on my part. The view is actually called [`pg_extension`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-extension.html), updating post

Comment: Also make sure you are in the right database before doing this. Extensions seem to be loaded on a per-database level.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I needed to add the schema to the function call like this: `app.uuid_generate_v4()`

instead of this: `uuid_generate_v4()`

I found the schema for each extension by running this query:

```
SELECT 
pge.extname,
pge.extversion,
pn.nspname AS schema
FROM pg_extension pge 
JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace pn ON pge.extnamespace = pn."oid" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometime you've just to run the line:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

just before the creation of the table

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. I just deleted extension and run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

And my problem solved.