# Creating default UUID generator in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, uuid

Could anyone help on how to create a column with `uuid` generator field which would generate random numbers automatically while inserting the row.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating a UUID in Postgres for Insert statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement)

Answer (score 5):

If you [install](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html) the [`uuid-ossp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html) extension, you can e.g. use `uuid_generate_v4()` for the default value of such a column:

```
create table selva
(
  uid uuid default uuid_generate_v4(),
  ... other columns ..
);
```