# Travis CI w/ Node.js and Postgresql: Error Relation Does Not Exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, travis-ci

Here's the output: https://travis-ci.org/maxdobeck/gateway/jobs/373773101.

Why am I getting this error:
`error: relation "members" does not exist`

I am able to use a .sql file to create the tables that I need but when it comes time to run tests the database says the tables don't exist?  Am I configuring the database correction incorrectly?

Comment: Are you sure that the script is connecting to the db `travis`? My first guess would be that you're either looking for the tables either in a wrong database or wrong schema.

Comment: That's what I've been leaning towards.  I just now saw the "Raw Log" button and when I pass in:
`$ psql -U postgres -d scheduler -c '\dt;'`

I get "No relations found".  So I must not be connecting to the correct database when I create my tables.  Unsure how to verify but now that I can test stuff with the raw log that helps.

Comment: can you check in these scripts if it is the case? https://travis-ci.org/maxdobeck/gateway/jobs/373773101#L481 I cant see their content

Comment: https://travis-ci.org/maxdobeck/gateway

Got the green light!

It was technically the Create tables script.  I was using the generate_uuid function like so:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement#12505220

adding the `create extension` line did the trick.

This error was pointing to real root cause: 
`psql:./db/migrations/travis_setup.sql:11: ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: awesome! good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 0):

It was technically the Create tables script. I was using the generate_uuid function like in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement#12505220)

Adding the create extension line did the trick.

This error was pointing to real root cause:

> ERROR: function
>   uuid_generate_v4() does not exist HINT: No function matches the given
>   name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I just fixed it. The problem is probably because travis cannot create the table which in your case is `members`.
You need to add the following lines in your `.travis.yaml` file

```
    before_script:
  - psql -c "create database yourdbname;" -U postgres
  - psql -c "create user dbusername WITH PASSWORD 'yourpassword';" -U postgres
```

create a script that contains the query for creating the table. mine resembles something like this.

```
const pg = require('pg');

const config = {
  user: 'yourdbusername', // this is the db user credential
  database: 'yourdb',
  password: 'yourdbpass',
  port: 5432,
  max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
  idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
};
const pool = new pg.Pool(config);

pool.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected to the Database');
});

/**
 * Create Tables
 */
const createTables = () => {
  const queryText = `your query`;

  pool
    .query(queryText)
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);
      pool.end();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      pool.end();
    });
};

pool.on('remove', () => {
  console.log('client removed');
  process.exit(0);
});

module.exports = {
  createTables,
  pool
};
require('make-runnable');
```

it will be preferable to make use of a remote database like elephantSQL or any other remote postgres db. 
Go to your `package.json` and add the following line under scripts

```
    "create": "node ./path/to/the/file createTables",
```

Now update your `before_script` to this

```
before_script:
  - psql -c "create database wayfarer;" -U postgres
  - psql -c "create user wayfarer WITH PASSWORD 'rrwcscrz1';" -U postgres
  - "npm run create"
```

Also make sure you'vev installed `make-runnable` and `pg` packages