# How can I create a Serial ID with as a string with common prefix (ie tag_1, tag_2, tag_3) in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postrges, I know how to create a table with a column that has a serial (number) id:

```
CREATE TABLE Tag (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

I prefer to have my ids have a human readable aspect to them though.  I usually do something like `tag_1, tag_2, tag_3` `usr_1, usr_2, usr_3`.

I've seen instructions on how to generate uuids ([Generating a UUID in Postgres for Insert statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement)), but I don't really need that.  The basic serial number is more than enough, I just want to prefix `tag_` to the beginning.

How can I create a Serial ID with as a string with common prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with a sequence, which you can add to your table as a default value concatenated via `||` with the prefix you want e.g.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tag_seq START WITH 1;

CREATE TABLE tag 
    (id TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT 'tag_'||nextval('tag_seq'::regclass), 
    name TEXT);
    
INSERT INTO tag (name) VALUES ('foo'),('bar');    
SELECT * FROM tag;
  id   | name 
-------+------
 tag_1 | foo
 tag_2 | bar
(2 Zeilen)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a1ba3808ca061cdf5f7d1e27273f4633)