# Generate a UUID in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, uuid

My tables make use of UUID values. I am inserting rows using SQL SQLWorkbench/J but I don't see how I can generate UUIDs when performing a SQL `INSERT INTO (-want-to-generate-uuid-here, '5', 'some value')`. Is there a way to generate UUIDs  with SQLWorkBench/J?

Thanks

Comment: For full and varied answers on generating UUID in PostgreSQL, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12505158/6710366

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating a UUID in Postgres for Insert statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505158/generating-a-uuid-in-postgres-for-insert-statement)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

then you can use `uuid_generate_v4()`.

Comment: With Postgres 13 you don't need the extension any more

Comment: You can use `gen_random_uuid ()` since PG13 without needing the `uuid-ossp` extension

Comment: @SvetlinZarev your comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 6):

Since Postgres 13, UUIDs can be geneerated with `gen_random_uuid ()` without needing the `uuid-ossp` extension

Answer (score -1):

> The simplest solution is gen_random_uuid():

```
insert into tableName (id)
values (gen_random_uuid())
```